# mysql high cpu usage after query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, cpu-usage

I noted that my webapp was slow when a high number of concurrent users was present. I checked the slow query log and saw that the queries were really slow. I optimized the queries which made them orders of magnitude faster.
I wanted to test the improvements by using jmeter on a test setup of the webapp. There were no longer queries showing up in the slow query log. However, mysql was still being responsible for hitting my cpu usage limits. I am testing my webapplication (php-mysql) using jmeter with 50 concurrent users.
I have the impression that the high cpu usage due to mysql is now caused by io (see raising bo when id goes to 0) below

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----                                                                                                              
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st                                                                                                              
 0  0      0 661176  93304 2772588    0    0    31    36   53   37  7  4 89  0  0                                                                                                             
 0  0      0 660340  93304 2772588    0    0     0     0  308  470  1  0 99  0  0                                                                                                             
 0  0      0 660628  93308 2772588    0    0     0   260  195  295  1  0 99  0  0                                                                                                             
 0  0      0 661200  93308 2772588    0    0     0     0  146  198  0  1 100  0  0                                                                                                            
 0  0      0 661916  93308 2772588    0    0     0     0  142  191  0  0 99  0  0                                                                                                             
 0  0      0 662316  93308 2772588    0    0     0     0  138  186  0  0 100  0  0                                                                                                            
20  0      0 653208  93308 2772912    0    0     0     0 4872 30909 52 24 25  0  0                                                                                                            
19  0      0 649944  93308 2773556    0    0     0   132 11721 43471 65 35  0  0  0                                                                                                           
20  0      0 644976  93308 2773964    0    0     0     0 15866 38612 67 33  0  0  0                                                                                                           
18  0      0 648112  93308 2774660    0    0     0     0 13294 42855 67 33  0  0  0                                                                                                           
 0  0      0 658116  93308 2775104    0    0     0     0 10501 31905 51 27 22  0  0                                                                                                           
 0  0      0 658664  93312 2775112    0    0     0   132  175  248  1  0 100  0  0                                                                                                            
 1  0      0 658856  93312 2775112    0    0     0     4 2083 4107  4  2 94  0  0                                                                                                             
11  0      0 654464  93312 2775444    0    0     0     0 16173 36335 49 26 25  0  0                                                                                                           
19  0      0 646824  93316 2775888    0    0     0   100 11019 39406 64 36  0  0  0                                                                                                           
23  0      0 641296  93316 2776400    0    0     0     0 9313 38328 67 33  0  0  0                                                                                                            
22  0      0 635852  93316 2776836    0    0     0     0 13444 38672 62 39  0  0  0                                                                                                           
21  0      0 626460  93316 2777348    0    0     0  8736 18256 39672 64 36  0  0  0                                                                                                           
20  0      0 621200  93316 2777812    0    0     0   152 10693 38579 65 35  0  0  0                                                                                                           
18  0      0 622536  93316 2778328    0    0     0     0 9613 40834 67 33  0  0  0                                                                                                            
19  0      0 622204  93316 2778812    0    0     0     0 17307 39435 66 35  0  0  0
```

I also insert a screenshot from the fluctuating CPU due to mysql (monitor from phpmyadmin):
[image]

Any advise on how I can avoid the CPU hitting its limit is very welcome!

Comment: cpu time is there to be used, when a process neeeds it.

Comment: I understand but when 50 concurrent users slow down the app by hitting the CPU limit, I thought there must be something wrong with my code or there must be suboptimal settings. I was hoping that someone could give me a hint in what direction to search based on the vmstat output and the monitor picture.

Comment: that is part of the learning process by increasing the number of parallel users, you can check, if there are locks, or slow queres(log) or if your code needs tuning, but 50 shouldn't make that difference. And if you nortice huge lags, maybe you need stringer hardware.

Comment: Currently running on a 4GB RAM, 2 core CPU at digital ocean. I thought this would be strong enough for a load of 50 users.

Comment: look at the slow query log, if there is some querys, that take so long. you must detect hwere the peaks are coming from and they should appear in the log. you should try it at dba, post your mysql.cnf. Also take a look at the error log, if the system noticed some thing is too smalk, it usually shows up there.

Comment: Show us the query.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Almost always, high CPU is solved by a better index or a reformulation of the query.  You cannot "tune your way out of high CPU".

Comment: The Questions graph does not make sense.  What does it come from?

Comment: The questions graph comes from the monitor in phpmyadmin. I presume it shows the number of queries. At the time the monitor was running, I was running a load test with JMeter simulating 50 concurrent users cycling through the same 3 webpages.
I already did a first step in optimizing the queries and currently none of them shows up in the slow query logs. Before the query optimizations and with a long_query_time of 1 second, several queries popped up in the slow query log. Like I said, after the rewrite of the queries, currently no query is showing up in the slow query log.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
B1) Run your JMeter test
B2) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;     and we will have workload of JMeter
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: With the information requested Aug 7 at 19:26 we can help you reduce CPU cycles required.